# Does thrust copy data if its device_vector is created from iterator?

Tags: c++, cuda, thrust

Suppose that I have the following code

```
float *raw_data;
cudaMalloc(&raw_data, 100*sizeof(float));
thrust::device_vector <float> vec(raw_data, raw_data+100);
```

When executing the last line, does thrust copy the memory from raw_data to that of the device_vector, or does it just set the corresponding range of the vector?

Thanks.

Comment: C and C++ are different languages. Do not add a C tag for C++-only questions.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
thrust::device_vector <float> vec(raw_data, raw_data+100);
```

`vec` variable is filled with data copied from  pointer variable `raw_data` of range 0 to 100.

It is using the  following constructor  to initialize the variable vec.

```
template<typename InputIterator >
__host__    device_vector (InputIterator first, InputIterator last)
```